# md-menu override default max-width in Angular 2

Tags: css, angular2-template, angular-material2

I'm  using Angular 2 , Angular Material and I am willing to display more data in a md-menu and, therefore, I need to set the max-width of the md-menu to a higher value. Its default value is of 280px.

```
    <img src="/assets/images/ic-notifications.png" [mdMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu"/> 
    <md-menu #appMenu="mdMenu"  [overlapTrigger]="false" yPosition="below" xPosition="before" class="notifications-dropdown">
        <button md-menu-item >
           <div class="row notification-row"> 
             <div>
               <span class="image-container"> Option 1 </span>
             </div>
           </div>
        </button>
    </md-menu>
```

In CSS file, I do this:

```
.mat-menu-panel.notifications-dropdown {
    max-width:none;
    width: 100vw; 
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-top: 24px;
    overflow: visible;
}

.notification-row{
    width: 424px;
}
```

In console, I can identify the class where the default value is set: `max-width:280px;` , and when I edit it in my console, it works perfectly, but even though I try to override it in my CSS code, I am not able to do that. I tried this, also:

```
.mat-menu-panel{
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

And this:

```
.cdk-overlay-container .mat-menu-panel{
     max-width:600px;
    width: 100vw;
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-top: 24px;
}
```

How can I override this default value?

Comment: Have you tried `!important` or a more powerful selector (e.g. including the parents etc)?

Comment: Try adding the `.mat-menu-panel.notifications-dropdown` styles to a global stylesheet instead of your component styles. Also see [this guide](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/customizing-component-styles.md)

Comment: Yes, I tried it this way: `.mat-menu-panel.notifications-dropdown {
    max-width:600px !important;
    width: 100vw; 
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-top: 24px;
    overflow: visible;
}`

Comment: I used it with <style> tags in my index.html. No result.

Comment: Yes, when I put it this time not in my index.html with` <style>` tags, but I put it in my global CSS file, it worked. Yes, this is the answer. Thank you, @WillHowell !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set the [View Encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) to None on your component:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './my.component.html' ,
    styleUrls: ['./my.component.css'], 
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

Then in your component css you can do exactly what you tried:

```
.mat-menu-panel.notifications-dropdown {
    max-width:none;
    width: 100vw; 
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-top: 24px;
    overflow: visible;
}

.notification-row{
    width: 424px;
}
```

> View Encapsulation = None means that Angular does no view
>   encapsulation. Angular adds the CSS to the global styles. The scoping
>   rules, isolations, and protections discussed earlier don't apply. This
>   is essentially the same as pasting the component's styles into the
>   HTML.

Comment: @AndreiMatracaru So this solution apply on every mat-menu components of the angular application? if yes, how to restrict it to a single component, and if possible on a single class like myMenu -> <mat-menu class="myMenu"> ...  ?

Comment: whats the [panelClass](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api#MatMenu) prop for then?

Comment: Btw [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4462) here.

Comment: @galki `panelClass` is aliased to `class`

Comment: just `min-width: unset !important` worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63465373/how-to-nowrap-text-in-mat-menu-button/63466406#63466406

Comment: Tried about 15 different things, until this approach finally worked. On Angular 14.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases the wrapper over `.mat-menu-panel` can be `.cdk-overlay-pane`, in that case css should be something like this.

```
.cdk-overlay-pane.mat-menu-panel {
    max-width: your_custom_value
}
```

Due to the css specificity rules, 2 classes of specificity are required in order to override the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

The same crazy problem for me... how I solved:

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane .mat-menu-panel {
  max-width: 436px;
}
```

At component SASS file

See: [Angular Component Styles - View Encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation)

and issue comment by [@gaiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4823555/galki) https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4462