# How to increase the width of the mat-menu-item?

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
<div fxHide fxHide.xs="false" fxHide.md="true">
  <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="my-menu">
    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let menu of repoService.toolbarMenu" class="mr-4" (click)="repoService.onToolbarClick(menu)"
    class="notifications-dropdown">

      <mat-icon *ngIf="menu.icon" aria-label="menu.key" class="mr-4">{{menu.icon}}</mat-icon>
      <span class="notification-row">{{menu.displayKey | translate}}</span>

    </button>
  </mat-menu>
```

Css File

```css
.mat-menu-panel.notifications-dropdown {
      max-width:none;
      width: 100vw; 
      margin-left: -8px;
      margin-top: 24px;
      overflow: visible;
  }
  
  .notification-row{
      width: 424px;
  }
```

I have already tried this, but it doesn't work for me!

[md-menu override default max-width in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45841459/md-menu-override-default-max-width-in-angular-2)

Comment: and your css is?

Comment: I haven't implemented any css code, actually that's the issue what i am facing. I am using scss. I cant understand how to increase the width of the menu item?

Comment: did you try adding styles in your scss file?

Comment: I have added my scss file.

Answer (score 39):

i had the same issue and solved it by overriding the mat-menu-panel max width property:

```
::ng-deep.mat-menu-panel {
  max-width: none !important;
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 20):

https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api

> @Input('class') panelClass: string
>
> This method takes classes set on the host mat-menu element and applies
> them on the menu template that displays in the overlay container.
> Otherwise, it's difficult to style the containing menu from outside
> the component.

```
<mat-menu class="my-class" ... >
```

component css (needs ng-deep due to cdk-overlay):

```
::ng-deep {.mat-menu-panel.my-class { width: 400px; } }
```

Comment: This seems broken. I tried it and the class is applied but the CSS on my class isn't in there. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-extauy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmenu-overview-example.html

Comment: The dropdown menu is pink when looking at your stackblitz using Chrome 91? What do you mean is broken? If you're looking to style the button, that's a separate element.

Comment: Yep it seems to be working now, I swear it was broken. Chrome or angular update?

Comment: This works if you add the styles in styles.css. If you want to keep the styles in the parent component css file, you have to use ng-deep, like `::ng-deep .mat-menu-panel.my-class {...}`

Comment: This actually works without overriding other elements with mat-menu if you use a custom class.

Comment: Clarified the need for ng-deep.

Answer (score 11):

On Angular 12, on the CSS page, the following worked for me, because it made the width fit flexibly per the dynamic contents. It also kept the menu well-aligned.

```
::ng-deep.mat-menu-panel {
  max-width:fit-content !important;
}
```

Comment: This was the best answer for me, it worked I am using 12 also

Answer (score 9):

**Note** I used Angular 7. I know this is related to Angular 2 but I hope someone will find this helpful.

I also needed to make the menu fixed width but then, I realised that the menu gets width from the content.

So, what you can do, is create an element that is not part of angular material and give that element its width. For example...

```
<div class="ProfileBar">
  <mat-icon [matMenuTriggerFor]="profileMenu"class="ProfileImage">account_circle</mat-icon>

  <mat-menu #profileMenu="matMenu">
    <div class="ProfileInfo">
      <mat-icon class="ProfileInfo-user-icon">account_circle</mat-icon>
      <p class="full-name">Some full name</p>
       <p class="nickname">@SomeNickname</p>
    </div>

    <button (click)="logout()" mat-menu-item>Logout <mat-icon>exit_to_app</maticon></button>
  </mat-menu>
</div>
```

So what we have here is a `ProfileInfo` class that on which you can put the width normally like this
`.ProfileInfo { width: 300px }` or something like that. That will give the menu its width and `mat-menu-items` will follow that width. You don't even have to make it functional, it can be only like

```
  <mat-menu #profileMenu="matMenu">
    <div class="ClassOnlyForTheWidth"></div>
  </mat-menu>
```

and that is it.

On another point, and I don't know if this is going to be of any use to you, you can completely remove material styling by putting `[class]="'MyClass'"`. This will remove the material styling all together and, for example, render a button element natively, depending on the browser you are using, without any styling. If you then do this, `[class]="'MyClass mat-menu-item'"`, it will return the styling of the menu item (or any angular component) but then you are back to the issues of this entire stackoverflow thread.

Enjoy and I hope this will help someone

Answer (score 7):

To style an individual menu, add an additional class to `<mat-menu>` and change the width. This works in Angular 9:

```html
<button mat-stroked-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="myMenu">Open Menu</button>
<mat-menu #myMenu="matMenu" class="my-menu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Approve</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Reject</button>
</mat-menu>
```

```css
::ng-deep .my-menu {
    width: 190px;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me with this exact implementation. `::ng-deep` is deprecated. Stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-menu-width. [Angular component styles](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles) says _Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools._

Answer (score 3):

With Angular Material **15** this is now:

```
::ng-deep {  
  .mat-mdc-menu-panel {  
    max-width: unset !important;  
  }  
}
```

**mat-menu-panel** changed to **mat-mdc-menu-panel**

Answer (score 3):

Most answers here list the deprecated `::ng-deep` approach.
Similar goes for the use of !important which should only be used if all else fails.

As many point out, the main issue is that google set a max-width property. For me, the following worked by adding it to my Angular 15 apps global SCSS:

```
.cdk-overlay-pane {
  div.mat-mdc-menu-panel {
    max-width: none;
  }
}
```

To then change the width of your specific menu, you can wrap all elements inside with a certain width and the menu will grow with that container.

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" yPosition="below" id="app-notifications-menu">
  <div id="my-menu-container">
    <button mat-menu-item>
      <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
      <span>Redial</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</mat-menu>
```

In the component CSS you then simply set your preferred width:
#my-menu-container {
width: 400px;
}

Comment: Thanks I've been scanning the internet and your answer is the only one that worked ! 
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It can be done as follow:

```
//.my-menu is the class of my mat-menu
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane .my-menu {
    min-width: 450px;
}
```

or

```
//.my-menu is the class of my mat-menu
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container .my-menu {
    max-width: none !important;
}
```

Comment: The first part of your answer worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Angular Material 15:

HTML

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class="your-menu-class">
...
</mat-menu>

CSS

.cdk-overlay-pane {
    div.mat-mdc-menu-panel.your-menu-class {
      max-width: max-content;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Angular v17) nothing posted here worked. I needed to use a mix of both approaches listed here. (`:ng-deep` and usage of panel class)

HTML:

```
<mat-menu class="notificationsMenu">
...
</mat-menu>
```

CSS:

```
::ng-deep.notificationsMenu 
  max-width: 500px !important
```

Simply using `notificationsMenu` as class didn't work. Also, don't forget that you can change `notificationsMenu` to your class' name.

Note that `!important` is also necessary to override the default `max-width`, as it gets priority over our class.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div fxHide fxHide.xs="false" fxHide.md="true">
            <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
                <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                <button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let menu of repoService.toolbarMenu" class="mr-40" (click)="repoService.onToolbarClick(menu)">
                    <mat-icon *ngIf="menu.icon" aria-label="menu.key" class="mr-4">{{menu.icon}}</mat-icon>
                    <span class="ml-8">{{menu.displayKey | translate}}</span>
                </button>
            </mat-menu>
        </div>
```

- We just need to make a minor change (class="mr-40") mr stands for margin right, mr take multiples of 2, so we can increase the width according to our need.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I set custom width to **mat-menu-item.** And it worked perfectly for me.

```html
<mat-menu #menu1="matMenu" class="my-menutttt">
  <button style="width: 128px"  mat-menu-item>Deal</button>
  <button  mat-menu-item>Note</button>
  <button  mat-menu-item>Call or Chat</button>
  <button  mat-menu-item>Appointment</button>
  <button  mat-menu-item> Task</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the content of the `mat-menu` and apply the width to the wrapper itself, like in the following example:

```
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
    Hello, John Doe!
  </button>
  <mat-menu #menu>
    <div class="mat-menu-autosize" style="width: 300px">
      <button mat-menu-item>Settings</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Help</button>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <button mat-menu-item>Logout</button>
    </div>
  </mat-menu>
```

Comment: You can also target the`mat-menu-autosize` class instead of setting the width directly

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

on view page (HTML)

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class="menu"> 
  <div class="notification-container">
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
  </div>
</mat-menu>
```

on style  (scss,css) page

```
::ng-deep.mat-menu-panel {
   max-width: none !important;
}
.notification-container{
  width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Angular 11 the following worked

In the component

```html
<mat-menu #profileDropdown="matMenu" xPosition="before" class="profile-dropdown">
...
</mat-menu>
```

In styles.scss

```css
.profile-dropdown { 
  width: 380px; 
  max-width: unset !important;
}
```

It is close to Stefan Norberg's answer, but his sample did not work for me as is. I had to add `max-width: unset !important;` and put this in top styles file, otherwise there was no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite max-width on the .mat-menu-panel.

**HTML**

```
<mat-menu class="menu">
```

**CSS**

```
.menu {
  width: 121px;
  max-width: 500px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`::ng-deep .mat-menu-panel {max-width: 300px}`