# How to nowrap text in mat-menu button?

Tags: css, angular

I have `mat-menu`:

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <button *ngFor="let doc of docs; let i = index" mat-menu-item>
             {{ i + 1 }}. {{ doc.name }} // Here long text
      </button>
</mat-menu>
```

How to wrap text inside `<button>` and remove dots if text so long?

I have tried: `white-space: nowrap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done if you set `mat-menu-panel` max-width to initial or bigger value than `280px` because the default value of `max-width: 280px;`

*style.scss*

```css
.main-menu.mat-menu-panel {
    max-width: initial !important
  }
```

*template*

```html
<mat-menu class="main-menu" #menu="matMenu">
 ....
</mat-menu>
```

[image: final result]

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ba7zcv?file=src/app/menu-overview-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can reset css properties:

```
white-space: normal;
overflow: visible;
text-overflow: clip;
```

Comment: For button or for mat class?