# Angular Material mat-menu min-width

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I want to create a rather small Material mat-menu in Angular 15.
Here is my code :

```
  <mat-menu #flagMenu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item>
      <img src="assets/flags/en.png" class="flag"/>
    </button>
    <button mat-menu-item>
      <img src="assets/flags/fr.png" class="flag"/>
    </button>
  </mat-menu>
```

I find that what I need is to unset the .mat-mdc-menu-panel.mat-mdc-menu-panel min-width
but I cannot figure out how to implement it in CSS, I tried to use !important, ng-deep and put it in my style.css file, but nothing works.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pme1y.png

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution

style.css

```
.mat-mdc-menu-panel.mat-mdc-menu-panel {
  min-width: unset !important;
}
```

i dont understand, i tried it before and didn't work

Comment: `initial` worked better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63465373/how-to-nowrap-text-in-mat-menu-button/63466406#63466406